# Unable to understand the Spring security multiple encode type usage

Tags: spring, security, spring-security, encoding, bcrypt

I am trying to understand the spring security multiple encoding.

Consider, I have a registration of username/password.

**Simply calling PasswordEncoder.encode(password)  How it will decide which type of encode has to happen ?

Also, If i directly give BCrypt object return, it is not considered as multiple right. AUtomatically, By itself how the Spring will understand, which one to use out of the implemented encoding types(noop/bcrypt/scrypt)** which i have given.

```
public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
Map<String, PasswordEncoder> encoders = new HashMap<>();
encoders.put("noop", NoOpPasswordEncoder.getInstance());
encoders.put("bcrypt", new BCryptPasswordEncoder());
encoders.put("scrypt", new SCryptPasswordEncoder());

return new DelegatingPasswordEncoder("bcrypt", encoders); 
} 
private final PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;
     

public UserAccount register(@RequestParam("username") String username, @RequestParam("password")  String password, @RequestParam("firstName") String firstName, @RequestParam("lastName") String lastName) {
UserAccount userAccount = new UserAccount();
userAccount.setUsername(username);
userAccount.setPassword(passwordEncoder.encode(password));
return userAccountRepository.save(userAccount);
```

}

I am trying to understand.

Answer (score 3):

```java
Map<String, PasswordEncoder> encoders = new HashMap<>();
encoders.put("noop", NoOpPasswordEncoder.getInstance());
encoders.put("bcrypt", new BCryptPasswordEncoder());
encoders.put("scrypt", new SCryptPasswordEncoder());
PasswordEncoder  passwordEncoder = new DelegatingPasswordEncoder("bcrypt", encoders);
```

The `bcrypt` passed to `DelegatingPasswordEncoder` 's constructor specifies which algorithm is used to encode a plain password.

So if you call :

```java
passordEncoder.encode("somePassword")
```

It will always use `BCryptPasswordEncoder` to encode this password. The encoded password will be prefixed by `{bcrypt}`.

The encoder map that passed to the `DelegatingPasswordEncoder` is for checking if an encoded password is matched with a raw password. So it is only useful when you call :

```java
passordEncoder.matches("rawPassword" , "encodedPassword")
```

If the encoded password is started with the following prefixes , the correspond encoders will be used.

- for the prefix `{noop}` , use `NoOpPasswordEncoder`
- for the prefix `{bcrypt}` ,  use `BCryptPasswordEncoder`
- for the prefix `{scrypt}` , use `SCryptPasswordEncoder`

If the encoded password does not start with any of these prefixes , it will throw exception complaining it cannot determine which password encoder to use.

It is designed in this way mainly for addressing the following issues as mentioned by the [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/features/authentication/password-storage.html#authentication-password-storage-dpe) :

> - Many applications use old password encodings that cannot easily migrate.
> - The best practice for password storage will change again.
> - As a framework, Spring Security cannot make breaking changes frequently.

The idea is also store the information about which password encoding algorithm is used to encode a password in the final encoded password value. So if in the future we change to use another better algorithm for encoding the password for the new users, we still have enough information to know which algorithm should be used for matching old users' password. Otherwise, old users will be affected if we simply change it to use the new encoding algorithm.

Comment: What if you already had in your database passwords that were encrypted using BCrypt yet they weren't stored prefixed with `{bcrypt}`? Would adding something like `encoders.put("", new BCryptPasswordEncoder());` address this concern?